# How to include npm dependencies in your Cordova plugin

Tags: javascript, cordova, typescript, node-modules, apache-cordova

I'm currently implementing a plugin for Cordova named `core-cordova` [(source code)](https://github.com/josemigallas/aerogear-js-sdk/tree/agcordova-212/packages/core-cordova) that has also a dependency from another NPM package.

The problem is after installing the plugin in my app using

```
$ cordova plugin add @aerogearservices/core-cordova
```

I have this error on the console:

> Uncaught module @aerogearservices/core not found

I think I have to bundle this dependency somehow into the plugin JS files but I haven't found out how. So far I've tried using `Browserify` to bundle everything into a `dist/core-cordova.js` and define this in the `Plugin.xml` as:

```
<js-module src="dist/core-cordova.js" name="MetricsService">
    <clobbers target="cordova.aerogear" />
</js-module>
```

Using this approach doesn't throw me any error however `aerogear` is an empty object:

```
// Browser's dev console

> window.cordova.aerogear;
-> {}

> window.cordova.aerogear.MetricsService;
-> undefined
```

I don't have a clue how to solve this, any ideas?

> **NOTE**: the source code is a work in progress, there might be changes or errors.

Comment: You placed `@aerogearservices/core` in the wrong dependency section. That's all. You absolutely don't need to bundle it. It goes under `dependencies` and not under `devDependencies` because it is dependency that is needed to use your package not to develop it.

Comment: @AluanHaddad thanks for replying, I tried this but it didn't fix it, I still see the same error. Cordova doesn't look into node_modules so that's not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the empty object issue using `webpack` to bundle the module, and setting the `libraryTarget` to `'window'` in my webpack config.

From the [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#expose-via-object-assignment):

> `libraryTarget: 'window'` - The return value of your entry point will be assigned to the window object using the output.library value.

Without this setting, the bundled script wouldn't export in a way that it could be read from my plugin. I think this is because when Cordova loads the JS, it wraps it with another function, which prevents the implicit assignment to the window object the script would do otherwise upon loading. Also, since my bundled script wasn't actually exporting anything, Cordova wouldn't pick anything up to assign to the window object from the `clobbers` tag.

Note with this setting, you can remove the `clobbers` tag as well.